# More efficient way of updating UI from Service than intents?

Tags: android, user-interface, service, performance, android-intent

I currently have a Service in Android that is a sample VOIP client so it listens out for SIP messages and if it recieves one it starts up an Activity screen with UI components.

Then the following SIP messages determine what the Activity is to display on the screen.
For example if its an incoming call it will display Answer or Reject or an outgoing call it will show a dialling screen.

At the minute I use Intents to let the Activity know what state it should display.

An example is as follows:

---

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(SIPEngine.SIP_TRYING_INTENT);
        i.putExtra("com.net.INCOMING", true);
        sendBroadcast(i);

        Intent x = new Intent();
        x.setAction(CallManager.SIP_INCOMING_CALL_INTENT);
        sendBroadcast(x);
        Log.d("INTENT SENT", "INTENT SENT INCOMING CALL AFTER PROCESSINVITE");
```

---

So the activity will have a broadcast reciever registered for these intents and will switch its state according to the last intent it received.

Sample code as follows:

---

```
       SipCallListener = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction(); 

                    if(SIPEngine.SIP_RINGING_INTENT.equals(action)){
                        Log.d("cda ", "Got RINGING action SIPENGINE");
                        ringingSetup();
                    }         

                    if(CallManager.SIP_INCOMING_CALL_INTENT.equals(action)){
                        Log.d("cda ", "Got PHONE RINGING action");
                        incomingCallSetup();
                    }  
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CallManager.SIP_INCOMING_CALL_INTENT);
        filter.addAction(CallManager.SIP_RINGING_CALL_INTENT);
        registerReceiver(SipCallListener, filter);
```

---

This works however it seems like it is not very efficient, the Intents will get broadcast system wide and Intents having to fire for different states seems like it could become inefficient the more I have to include as well as adding complexity.

So I was wondering if there is a different more efficient and cleaner way to do this?

Is there a way to keep Intents broadcasting only inside an application?

Would callbacks be a better idea? If so why and in what way should they be implemented?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**UPDATE 2015:**

This question/answer still gets a little bit of activity, but it is over 5 yrs old and things have changed quite a bit.  5 years ago, the answer below was how I would have handled it.  Later I wrote a very lightweight dependency injection solution that I was using for a while (which I mentioned in the comments).  Nowadays, I would answer this question using Dagger and RxAndroid.  Dagger to inject a "mediator" class into both the Service and all Activities that need to be notified, the Service would push the status update to the mediator class, and the mediator class would expose an observable for the activities to consume the status update (in place of the OP's broadcast receiver).

**Original answer**

I usually subclass Application and let my in-app communication go through this class (or have a mediator owned by the Application do the work...regardless, the Application being the entry point for the service to communicate with).  I have a bound service that needs to update the UI as well (much simpler than yours, but the same idea) and it basically tells the app its new state and the app can then pass this information along in one way or another to the currently active activity.  You can also maintain a pointer to the currently active activity (if there is more than one), and make decisions whether or not to simply update the current activity, broadcast the intent to launch a different activity, ignore the message, etc.  I would also subclass Activity and have your new activity base class tell the Application that it is currently the active one in onResume and that it is being paused in onPause (for cases where your service is running in the background and the activities are all paused).

**EDIT:**

In response to the comment, here's more specifics.

Your application currently consists of Activity-derived and Service-derived classes for the most part.  Inherently, you get functionality from an instance of the android.app.Application class.  This is declared in your manifest (by default) with the following line:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

The application element in your manifest doesn't use the android:name attribute, so it just creates an instance of the default android.app.Application class to represent your global application context.

In my apps, I create a subclass of Application (ApplicationEx, for example) and I tell my app through the manifest that this is the class to instantiate as MY global application context.  For example:

```
<application
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.app.ApplicationEx"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I can now add methods to ApplicationEx for activities and services to use to communicate.  There is always a single instance of your global application context, so this is your starting point if anything needs to be global for your app.

A second piece of this is that instead of deriving my services and activities from Service and Activity, I create a subclass of each with a getAppContext method that casts the return value of getApplicationContext (which exists already in both of these classes because they derive from Context) to my ApplicationEx class.

So........

All that being said, you add a CurrentActivity property to your ApplicationEx class of type Activity (or ActivityBase if you subclass it as I do).  In ActivityBase's onResume method, you pass yourself to ApplicationEx for it to set CurrentActivity to that activity.  Now, you can expose methods on ApplicationEx to pass information directly to the current activity instead of relying on the Intent mechanisms.

That's about as clear as I can make it

Comment: I have read your post a couple of times Rich and I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide a link to an example of how its done that way?

Comment: I provided further explanation above...let me know if you have more ?s or if it's not clear.

Comment: can i handle an IntentService callback message from the application?

Comment: Question to you, Rich. 
On one hand I found your idea really interesting, as it allows to build applications with some sort of DI a la Spring (which I used in my project to great success!)
On the other hand, I scanned the android's dev-guide for the thing you described, but found nothing. 
So my question is, is it really recommended by google to use the direct references between all app's artifacts instead of IPC or other funny old-school techniques? are there any limitations, pitfalls or gotchas with that?
TIA

Comment: @injecteer This answer is 2 1/2 years old.  I have since built my own lightweight DI container that I included in a little standard lib I posted to Github.  I haven't fully filled out the readme file with examples, but I started a sample project that makes use of it.  The class in question is ServiceLocator.  I'd be glad to discuss my implementation, how I use it, etc.  https://github.com/aguynamedrich/beacon-utils

Comment: please write a Tutorial for this excellent answer @Rich its a request .

Comment: Excellent explanation. I have read dagger again and again. Still feel like a magic is behind it. But now I have a feel about the science behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You can send broadcast intents just to your own application and not system wide with [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html):

Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process. This is has a number of advantages over sending global broadcasts with sendBroadcast(Intent):

> You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so don't need to worry about leaking private data.
>
> It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts to your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes they can exploit.
>
> It is more efficient than sending a global broadcast through the system.

However, I'd still recommend going with the Service approach and locally binding and talking through Handler when necessary to update UI components for efficiency.