# Service bound to first Activity in stack means Service lives forever until App stops?

Tags: android, android-service-binding

If I bind a service to the main first Activity in an app. Then I open multiple activities on top of that, will the service always live on even when the Activity it is bound to is in onPause(). A service can not be "paused", right? Will it not be killed until all the Activities on top of it has been popped off the stack and finally also the Activity the Service is bound to?

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but it defines binding it to activity vs application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154899/binding-a-service-to-an-android-app-activity-vs-binding-it-to-an-android-app-app