# Multiple activities binding to a service

Tags: android, binding, service, android-activity

I have a service component (common task for all my apps), which can be invoked by any of the apps. I am trying to access the service object from the all activities, I noticed that the one which created the service [startService(intent)] has the right informaion. But rest does not get the informaion needed. My Code is as below:

```
// Activity.java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Intent intent = new Intent (this.context, Service.class) ;
    this.context.startService(intent) ;
    this.context.bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE) ;
    ...
    String result = serviceObj.getData() ;
}

public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    serviceObj = ((Service.LocalBinder)service).getService();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5000, 60000 ) ;
}



// Service.java

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    Service getService() {
        return Service.this;
    }
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext() ;
}

public void onStart( Intent intent, int startId ) {

... some processing is done here...

}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
```

If I invoke startService(intent). it creates a new service and runs in parallel to the other service.

If I don't invoke startService(intent), serviceObj.getData() retuns null value.

Can any one enlighten me where have I gone wrong.

Any kind of pointer will be very useful..

Thanks and regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I invoke startService(intent). it creates a new service and runs in parallel to the other service.

No, it does not. There will be at most one instance of your service running.

> If I don't invoke startService(intent), serviceObj.getData() retuns null value.

`startService()` has nothing to do with it, from my reading of your code. You are attempting to use `serviceObj` in `onCreate()`. That will never work. `bindService()` is an asynchronous call. You cannot use `serviveObj` until `onServiceConnected()` is called. `onServiceConnected()` will not be called until sometime after `onCreate()` returns.

Also:

- While there are cases when you might need both `startService()` and `bindService()`, they are not both needed in the normal case.
- Do not use `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped me.

Regarding the service running in parallel to the other, I found that this was due to "new Intent (this.context, Service.class)". 

I replaced this with "new Intent ("com.package", "com.package.service");" 

Thanks for the pointers..

Comment: You are saying "Do not use getApplicationContext". So, would that apply to the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141632/android-service-interacting-with-multiple-activities also? I the answer "wrong" / against the rules one there?

Comment: @OneWorld: I am definitely not a fan of the "stick an `Activity` in the `Application` to track the "current" activity" pattern. If nothing else, a static data member works just as well and with greater flexibility. Beyond that, preventing an `Activity` from being garbage collected is a prescription for trouble.