# Update UI from service

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [More efficient way of updating UI from Service than intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621395/more-efficient-way-of-updating-ui-from-service-than-intents)

I have a RSS Feed reader application. I am handling the feed reading in a service, but I don't know how to update the UI. What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion to you is, create a [handler](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html) for the UI part which updates the text field or UI components.

Secondly, have notifications from the service to the activity by way of interface class.