# Updating android from service

Tags: android, user-interface, service

I am searching for a solution to update the UI from a service.

The best solution I found is this one:

> subclass Application and let in-app
>   communication go through this class

As suggested here [More efficient way of updating UI from Service than intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621395/more-efficient-way-of-updating-ui-from-service-than-intents).

Unfortunately I am new to Android and Java programming, so I do not really understand how this works.

It would help me very much, if someone could create a working example project from the given code snippets in the solution. An app that starts a service, increases a counter and displays the counter in textview would be a good and simple example.  I think I will understand this much better than a therotical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/android-restful-api-service/3197456#3197456) to a similar question where there is a full example. If you are just doing some basic background task, an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) may be a better solution though.

Comment: thanks, but i need example code for the 'efficient way' - not using handlers etc. - just subclass application - this sounds much more efficient.

Comment: That is the efficient way. It uses a Local Service so any IPC is short circuited, no aidl, etc.

Comment: Well, as i said i am new to this kind of stuff, but as far as i understand the approach to subclass Application lets in-app communication go through this class. This means i could directly update the UI from the service without using any handler - this did sound very interesting, thats why i asked for an example for this solution.

Comment: Now im very confused.  How does subclassing activity have anything to do with making a service communicate with an activity?