# Check Database at every seconds

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

In My application I want to check data after every second, using service.
I have tried to use Timer but it doesn't allow me to use 'runOnUiThread' in service.
In Activity Timer works fine.

or

Is there any other way to trace database at every seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a Runnable, that way you **can** use the `runOnUiThread(runnable)` functionality.

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      //do ui update
   }
};
```

Edit: try this: [More efficient way of updating UI from Service than intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621395/more-efficient-way-of-updating-ui-from-service-than-intents)

Edit2: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: but it show me this error **The method runOnUiThread(Runnable) is undefined for the type DiallCallService**, if I use the same method runOnUiThread(Runnable) for acitviyt it works fine.

Comment: I didn't read that you were running from a service .. my bad.

Comment: Is there any other options that I can call particular method whenever the system time is changed?

Comment: Yes i included a link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use thread u can trace the data base every time

```
    try{
        thread=new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(set) {
                    thread_Run();
                }
            }
        };

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```