# How to update UI and wait till update is done

Tags: android

Using android sdk 2.3. How can I synchronously update the UI from a service. I just need to update a text view in an Activity but it has to be synchronous, so my worker thread needs to stop for a bit. On iOS there is performSelectorOnMainThread  waitUnitDone

I can't find a waitUntil done on Android using runOnUIThread etc

Thanks

Comment: Have you done some research? There are plenty of similar questions on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/restful-api-service/3197456#3197456, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621395/more-efficient-way-of-updating-ui-from-service-than-intents etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to update UI in android after completing task in worker thread. you can go for [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Other way to do this efficiently is by using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
[runOnUithread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is also one of the option.

Comment: I'm sorry to do some necromancy, but I have the same problem. Your answer doesn't fit the problem. The worker thread sends a request to UI thread, then has to wait until UI was changed. Your answer tells us, how to do an UI update, after worker is finished.

Comment: This answer was not intended to suit your requirement. This answer was a reply to the above question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missunderstanding the question, but the creator seemed to have the same problem as I had. That's why I wrote 'I have the same problem'. And for that, you answer the other way round as asked.