# How to update UI from Android service using RxJava/RxAndroid

Tags: android, android-service, rx-java, ui-thread, rx-android

I have a Bound Service which responsible for downloading files and thus it knows the downloading status/progress. And the UI (Fragment or Activity) has to show/update download progress from the service.

Actually i think the common way is to use `BroadcastReciever` or a `CallBack` from Activity. But i heard somewhere about using RxJava (ReactiveX Programming) and **mediator** class (and Dagger to inject it into both service and activity) which is mentioned below.

So my question is how to handle RxJava with these bunch of stuff? Any Code Samples? Is there another efficient way than using intents?

Resource:
[More efficient way of updating UI from Service than intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621395/more-efficient-way-of-updating-ui-from-service-than-intents) [ see the first answer update ]

Comment: Personally I prefer using Messenger service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

Comment: I thought I had an example of using Messenger somewhere here, I guess not, but here's a good post detailing its use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging

Comment: just use "local bound service" pattern, no need for any external libs and it is the fastest solution

Comment: @pskink, you mean pass a Callback to bound service and use it retrieve new download progress?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i mean, but if you store your downloads in some sqlite db you could use a CursorLoader that queries your custom ContentProvider and the service updates/inserts/deletes your provider, in this case there is no need for any callbacks

Comment: @AmirHoseinKazemNejad It's not exactly what you are looking for but maybe this article will inspire you http://www.donnfelker.com/rxjava-with-aidl-services/

Answer (score 15):

**Required of RxJava/RxAndroid**

**1) OBSERVABLES
2) OBSERVERS
3) SUBSCRIBE**

Plan where you need to place your **1**, **2**, **3**,

***OBSERVABLES*** go where the data is created, so In your case **SERVICE**

***OBSERVERS*** go where the data needs to be consumed(or displayed), so that's your **ACTIVITY**

***SUBSCRIBE*** goes anywhere where you have access to OBSERVABLE & OBSERVER, so lets use **ACVITITY** for that

***Procedure and Code:***

Firstly,
Prepare your OBSERVABLE in service like this

```
class MyService extends Service {
    static PublishSubject<String> data = PublishSubject.create();

   @Override
   public void onStarCommand(Intent intent,int i, int j){
        # DO THIS ANYWHER WHERE YOU GENERATE DATA 
        data.onNext("Hello");
   }

   public static Observable<String> getObservable(){
      return data;
   }
}
```

Secondly, 
Prepare your OBSERVER(and OBSERVABLE) in Activity's onCreate

```
Observable<String> observable = MyService.getObservable();
Observer<String> observer = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ",e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String text) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DATA reveived here: "+text);
        }
    };
```

Lastly 
Link both OBSERVER and OBSERVABLE in Activity, else Observable will not respond,
use this again in onCreate

```
observable.subscribe(observer);
```

DONE, Now when even the data is triggered from Service using  onNext(), the data arrives in Activity

Comment: And how to do this without static fields?

Comment: `public void onCompleted()` should be `public void onComplete()`. Also missing onSubscribe() method.

Comment: app crashes when activity/fragment is destroyed or not active.. how to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

The `Binder` subclass you use when something binds to your `Service` can expose a method that returns an `Observable` which emits progress data.

The caveat with this approach is that you have two resources which you need to release when the `Activity` instance is no longer valid: the service connection and the observable subscription.

Comment: can you explain your comment , or give some example ?

Comment: Bad answer. Observable is not serialized object, so not sure if it will work, especially if service is designed for cross-process interaction. Wont work.

Comment: Cross-process interaction is outside the scope of this question. Otherwise, it's basically the same as exposing your Service instance via the Binder, and the Service is also not serializable.

Comment: @LeonardoAcevedo, haven't tested, but shouldn't work

Comment: @msangel for a local bound service there should be no need for serialization, do you think that would work on that case?